# Many requestShippingRates errors

Tags: debugging, magento, php

I cannot seem to find out how to track down this bug: I can see it has something to do with Shipping Rates, but there's very little information being posted into the error log.

```
2013-01-08T15:45:36+01:00 DEBUG (7): requestShippingRates
```

There are many of these errors being posted.

Comment: DEBUG means, DEBUG, it is no error. Some developer added a debug message via Mage::log('requestShippingRates' ... You can just grep after the string, but I think there is no need to worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have shell access, try using the following command to search for instances of requestShippingRates. Run it from your /var/www/app directory. the * means look at everyting, the -R means recurse directories, and the -i means ignore upper / lowercase.

```
 grep "requestShippingRates" * -R -i
```

You did not mention whether or not these errors are showing up in your php log, but you could also grep the following:

```
grep "error_log(" * -R -i
```

That will show anything written to the php error log.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities, one is that the string is contained in your code, so simply searching the project for 'requestShippingRates', and find the one that is a string being passed to `Mage::log`. The other, which is probably more likely, is that at some point somebody has put something along the lines of `Mage::log(__FUNCTION__)` in one of the `requestShippingRates` functions. You should be able to find that easy enough by searching for `n requestShippingRates` (i.e. match the n at the end of a function declaration).